# Azure DataBricks : How to do inner join of two dataframes which has one to many relationship and select particular columns from both dataframes.?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have read data from json files in following way :

```
import os,shutil,glob,time
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim 

#Get Data DF1
df1 = spark.read.format("json").load("/mnt/coi/df1.json")

#Get Data DF2
df2 = spark.read.format("json").load("/mnt/coi/df2.json")
```

I am joining the data and selecting columns from both DF but end-result is not proper and do not have all the data :

```
df = df2.join(df1,df2.Number == df1.Number,how="inner").select(df1.abc,df2.xyz)
```

DF1 JSON which has unique **Number** column values

```
{"Number":80216883,"Type":"8","ID":2,"Code":"1290","abc":"M0"} 
{"Number":80216884,"Type":"8","ID":2,"Code":"1010","abc":"MT"} 
{"Number":80216885,"Type":"8","ID":2,"Code":"1295","abc":"MS"}
```

DF2 JSON which has duplicate  **Number** values

```
{"Number":80216883,"DateTime":"2019-11-16","Year":2020,"Quarter":2,"xyz":5,"abc":"M0"}
{"Number":80216883,"DateTime":"2018-11-20","Year":2020,"Quarter":2,"xyz":5,"abc":"M0"}
{"Number":80216884,"DateTime":"2019-11-09","Year":2020,"Quarter":2,"xyz":5,"abc":"MT"}
```

Result i want is :         `{"Number":80216883,"Type":"8","ID":2,"Code":"1290","abc":"M0","DateTime":"2018-11-16","Year":2020,"Quarter":2,"xyz":5}      {"Number":80216883,"Type":"8","ID":2,"Code":"1290","abc":"M0","DateTime":"2018-11-20","Year":2020,"Quarter":2,"xyz":5}`

> How to do inner join of two dataframes which has one to many
>   relationship and select particular columns from both dataframes.?

When i do the join some of the **Number** which are present in two DF are not there in final output json.

**Also while merging a part files into one file only last part file is getting copied to final data PFB code :**

```
dfAll.write.format("json").save("/mnt/coi/DataModel")

#Read Part files
path = glob.glob("/dbfs/mnt/coi/DataModel/part-000*.json")


#Move file to FinalData folder in blbo
for file in path: 
      shutil.move(file,"/dbfs/mnt/coi/FinalData/FinalData.json")
```

Comment: What is wrong with the results you get? Could you add some example input/output to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Can you give us one example of your json structure?

Comment: @ptfaferreira@shaido : Added json

Comment: The inner join you apply returns the expected result for me. Can give us the expected result you want? With that will be easier to help you :)

Comment: @ptfaferreira updated with result ( i am using python (spark))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your expect result, considering that you only want the values from the relation form 1 to many, my approach is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df2.join(df1,df2.Number == df1.Number,how="inner").select(df2.DateTime,df2.Number,df2.Quarter,df2.Year,df2.abc,df2.xyz)

df3 = df.groupBy("Number").count().filter(col("count")>1).select(df.Number)

df4=df3.join(df, df.Number == df3.Number,how="inner")

display(df4)
```

Tell me if this help you or not please.

Comment: I figured out the root cause of the issue its not join that causing a issue. its merging of part json files into one final json files giving a issue

Comment: dfAllReqData.write.format("json").save("/mnt/coi/DataModel")

#Read Part files
path = glob.glob("/dbfs/mnt/coi/DataModel/")

Move file to FinalData folder in blbo
for file in path: 
      shutil.move(file,"/dbfs/mnt/coi/FinalData/FinalData.json")